# Solving linear equation with three variables

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

1)Do equations with 3 variables require at least 3 equation for us to solve without any dependent variable?
2)if two equations of such kind equate to zero for eg: a-b+2c=0 and 3a+b+c=0.  Then using the matrice ,there is a method to solve them...explain that method.is there a proof or is it related to Gaussian method which is out of my scope?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Describing_the_solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)For linear equations over the reals, yes, you need as many equations as variables.  In the usual case you will have a unique solution.  For equations over the naturals, you can sometimes get by with less.  Also consider $x^2+y^2+z^2=0$  That looks like one equation, but there is only one solution in the reals for three variables.

2)The matrix method works fine with two equations with no constant.  You may have equations that are inconsistent or duplicative, but that can happen with a constant as well.

Comment: So that means as many equations as variables will be required if an explicit constant is present( i.e not as a coefficient )? Can you explain matrice method?

Comment: Explaining the matrix approach to simultaneous equations seems to me like writing a textbook chapter-it is not a specific enough question to fit here.

Comment: I had no idea. so that means as many equations as variables will be required if an explicit constant is present ?